# How to map and bind Dropdown items in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

i have  a dropdown which has option like **testOptions**.

i get data from service for these option to Map like 'Y' for Yes , 'N' for 'No' and 'U' for unconfirmed in  property **optionTest** .

```
    import { Component, OnInit, createPlatformFactory } from '@angular/core';


    @Component({
    selector: 'app-test-information',
    templateUrl: './app-test-information.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app-test-information.component.scss']
    })
    export class TestInfoComponent implements OnInit {

    Id :Items;
    public testOptions: Items[] = [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: 'NA',
    },

    {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Yes',
    },

    {
    id: 3,
    name: 'No',
    },

    {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Unconfirmed'
    }
    ];

    ngOnInit() {

    this.infoService.getData()
    .subscribe((result :InfoResults ) => this.data = result
    , undefined,
    () => {
    if (this.data) {
    this.readOnlyData()

    }

    })


    readOnlyData() {
 //here i am trying to find item in testOptions and bind the data from service
    this.Id=this.testOptions.find((item) => item.name === "Yes" ) ;

    }
    }


  <!-- Model class for items : -->

    export class Items {
    public id ?: number;
    public name : string;
    }
```

```
  export class InfoResults {
  public optionTest : string;
  }
```

how we can map or get `this.id` if options from service are coming in data like 'Y' for Yes , 'N' for 'No' and 'U' for unconfirmed?

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to group the array based on property value of 'Y' , 'N' and 'U' if i understand it correctly ? If not, please describe it more like providing the input and expected output

Comment: @Ethan.. Yes, you are right .